# Can a part (component) class be a member of two assembly (collection) classes?

Tags: uml

How would you represent a relationship where an instance of a class is part of two (or more) instances of different classes?

Comment: I don't get it. Can you show the class model you rely on? Or make some kind of example?

Comment: As a newbie to stackOverflow, I can't post a diagram, so I will describe my diagram.  Imagine two classes that are positioned next to each other, horizontally.  Then imagine a third class positioned below the two classes.  Finally imagine a composition line drawn from each of those two classes down to the third class.  The diamond is on end of the line that meets the two classes.  This shows that the bottom class is a part of each to the two top classes.

Comment: Put your image on a public server. I can move it to your post.

Answer (score 0):

That is what the **shared** AggregationKind is for (aka Aggregation).

You draw that as an association with a open diamond at the *whole* end.

If the `Part` class **must** always be part of both a `Whole1` instance as a `Whole2` instance, you can indicate that with the multiplicity `1`
[image]

Comment: As a newbie to stackOverflow, I can't post a diagram, so I will describe my diagram.

Comment: Mr. Bellekens, as I understand, an aggregation at the whole end means that the multiplicity is either 0 or 1.  This in turn means that class at the other end (target), may or may not be part of the whole.  This is not quite the same as "the target must be part of two different classes."  In my original post, I hoped to ask whether a class can be a part of two different classes, simultaneously.

Comment: Thanks for the diagram!!  The diamond is clear, which means it is an aggregation. A composition is represented with a solid diamond.  I now understand that a part can be a member or multiple aggregations and a part can be a member of, at most, one composition.    Correct?     Question: If a part is a member of one "aggregation", then can it also be a member of a composition?  I'm guessing no.

Comment: Yes, you're right in your last comment. A single class object can be a part of at most one composite aggregation (aka composition, but composite aggregation is the term used in specification) and (at the same time) any number of shared aggregations (or aggregations, same comment as previously applies).

Answer (score 0):

I guess your wording is incorrect, since this has got nothing to do with instances. If a class is referenced in two collections you simply have two associations:

[image]

`C` is referenced from `B` as attribute `c` with a multiplicity `*`. Dito for `A`. The dot says that the role names (the two `c`s) are owned properties of the opposite side class.

There is no need to denote any aggregation if not required. If, and only if, use a composite aggregation which binds objects strong (that is, they die when all their compositors are dead). Don't use shared aggregation since it has an open semantic which needs to be defined in the domain before use.

Comment: Still not sure without a picture from you. Maybe you're talking about ternary associations?